# Find the principal value of $\big[\frac{e}{2}(-1-\sqrt3i)\big]^{3\pi i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-principal-value

I have been asked to find the principal value of: $\big[\frac{e}{2}(-1-\sqrt3i)\big]^{3\pi i}$

The textbook *Complex Variables with Applications* by A. David Wunsch only provides answers to the odd questions and I have found myself at a loss. All examples I have found have been much simpler in nature. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is the $i$ under the radical, or does it, in fact, belong outside?

Comment: Write the complex number $\frac{e}{2}(-1-\sqrt{3}i)$ in polar form, and then raise it to the power $3\pi i$.

Comment: You are correct that is my mistype, the i does belong outside - I will correct.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
  & \left(\frac e2(-1-\sqrt{3}i)\right)^{3\pi i} \\
= & e^{3\pi i}\cdot\left(-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)^{3\pi i} \\
= & (e^{\pi i})^3\cdot\left(e^{\tfrac{-2\pi i}3}\right)^{3\pi i} \\
= & (-1)^3\cdot e^{\tfrac{-2\pi i}3\cdot3\pi i} \\
= & -e^{2\pi^2} \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$1+i\sqrt 3 = 2 (\frac 12 + i \frac {\sqrt {3}}{2}) = 2(\cos \frac {\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac {\pi}{3}) = 2e^{\frac {\pi}{3}i}$

$\left((\frac {e}{2})(2e^{\frac {\pi}{3}i})\right)^{3\pi i}\\
\left(e^{\frac {\pi}{3}i+1}\right)^{3\pi i}\\
e^{(\frac {\pi}{3}i+1)\cdot (3\pi i)}\\
(e^{-\pi^2}e^{3\pi i})\\
e^{3\pi i} = -1\\
-e^{-\pi^2}\\
$

Comment: The question asks for $-1 - i\sqrt{3}$, perhaps you may write the angle as $\frac{-2 \pi}{3}$ to correct it?